# What will happen if both players have no money but Terran can fly base in map's edge?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

I've played with some "cheap" Terran players who's supposed to be defeated but they flied their base in the edge of the map (accessible only by air units) and wait till the opponent produces a flying unit to destroy their base.

It's annoying but manageable, but what if the other player has no more probe/drone/nexus/hatchery and can't afford to buy flying units anymore? Would both players be stuck until one player quits out of boredom? If that's the case, should Blizzard patch this and the Terran base should auto-destruct if he has no more units since the player is obviously just "trolling"?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According the [liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Stalemate_Detection) stalemate detection has been in SC2 ever since patch 1.2:

> A stalemate occurs when all players are unable to complete any of the following actions:
>
> - Generate income
> - Produce a unit
> - Construct a building
> - Research an upgrade
> - Destroy an enemy building.
>
> After three (in-game) minutes, if no player has completed any of these actions, the game issues a final three minute warning. If these final three minutes elapse without a player completing any of these actions, the game ends in a draw for all remaining players. If a player completes any of these actions, the timer resets and play continues normally.

If you think its unfair for some reason that the terran can force a draw in this situation even if you have a lot of ground units... All's fair in love and war

Comment: +1 the last part especially.  I really get annoyed by base hiding, but at the same time, if the map is totally out of money (or they disabled your ability to harvest) it sounds like a draw to me.